# Angular 6 (blur) function

Tags: angular6, angular7

I am using `(blur)` to update the user entered value after focus out.
In blur event if I touch the field and tab out without any changes.
("I want to restrict the service call for above behavior ")

Scenario:
If user touched the field but not change any value then I am tab out. For this scenario I want to restrict calling of service call method

I tried:

```html
<input (blur)="(username.touched && username.dirty && serviceCall())" #username="ngModel"/>
```

But the above code works only once.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] explaining the problem?

Comment: <input  (blur)="username.touched && username.dirty && serviceCall()"   #username="ngModel"/>

Comment: I am a bit confused as to the current behavior vs the expected behavior.  What do you mean by "I want to restrict the service call for above behavior"  and "But the above code works only once."

Comment: If user touched the field but not change any value then I am tab out. For this scenario I want to restrict calling of service call method